# Plot labels when 2 Moving Averages cross one another — Pinescript v4 (TradingView)

Tags: pine-script, moving-average, algorithmic-trading

LonesomeTheBlue wrote a pretty nifty script for plotting Moving Averages on different timeframes. More about his script here: [Moving Average MTF Live [Experimental] by LonesomeTheBlue](https://uk.tradingview.com/script/rIxDyvwR-Moving-Average-MTF-Live-Experimental/)

I'm trying to plot 'buy' and 'sell' labels for when these two MA's cross one another, but having problems doing so.

```html
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © LonesomeTheBlue

//@version=4
study("[CS] Moving Average MTF Live [Experimental]", overlay = true)

tf = input('5', type = input.resolution)
fastlen = input(7)
slowlen = input(200)

// get HTF moving averages
emafast = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ema(close, fastlen), lookahead = true)
emafastcur = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ema(close, fastlen), lookahead = false)
emaslow = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ema(close, slowlen), lookahead = true)
emaslowcur = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ema(close, slowlen), lookahead = false)

// is this last bar?
islast = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, barstate.islast, lookahead = true)

//if not last bar then draw non-repaint historical moving average
plot(islast ? na : emafast, color = islast ? na : color.lime, linewidth = 2)
plot(islast ? na : emaslow, color = islast ? na : color.red, linewidth = 2)

//calculate and keep the beginning of line
lastbar_index = 0
lastbar_index := change(time(tf)) != 0 ? 0 : nz(lastbar_index[1]) + 1

// draw real time higher time frame moving averare
line emahtffast = line.new(bar_index, emafastcur, bar_index - lastbar_index, emafastcur, color = color.blue, width = 0)
line emahtfslow = line.new(bar_index, emaslowcur, bar_index - lastbar_index, emaslowcur, color = color.red, width = 0)

// delete old lines if it's not the last one in htf periof
if change(time(tf)) == 0
    line.delete(emahtffast[1])
    line.delete(emahtfslow[1])
```

I've tried the following to no success. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but would appreciate any help from one of you talented peeps! Thanks in advance.

```html
    // buy+sell conditions / styling
    buyCond = crossover(emahtffast, emahtfslow)
    sellCond = crossunder(emahtfslow, emahtffast)

    plotshape(buyCond, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.normal, location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime)
    plotshape(sellCond, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.normal, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red)
```